# Problem with globe in cartopy

Tags: python, globe, cartopy

I have radar meteorological data in an Azimuthal Equidistant projection and I want to georreference it. I would know how to do it if the data were refered to the typical WGS-84 ellipsoid, but it isn't the case.

There are metadata in my file that says that `earth_radius = 637813700`, (so, spherical Earth, it seems), and `inverse_flatting = 298257224`. If I define a Globe cartopy instance to account for this,

```
globe = ccrs.Globe(semimajor_axis=637813700, inverse_flattening=298.257224)
```

and the rest as

```
lon0 = 344.38556
lat0 = 28.01861
map_proj = ccrs.AzimuthalEquidistant(central_latitude=lat0, central_longitude=lon0, globe=globe)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 16))                                                                                           
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = ccrs.PlateCarree(globe=globe))                                                        
ax.set_aspect("equal")                                                                                                       
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_dim, y_dim) 
pm = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, data, transform = map_proj)                                                                                                                                                                    
ax.coastlines("10m")                                                                                                         
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)                                                                                               
plt.colorbar(pm)                                                                                                            
plt.show()
```

I can't see the coastlines (and I need them), while if I just ignore the `Globe` instance, I see them. I am seeing a high resolution image when I include the `Globe` instance (I see it from the values of gridlines), while if I do not include `Globe`, I see a wider area). So how can I specify correctly the `Globe`, since I have to include it due to the fact that I am not in the WGS-84 projection?

Comment: What happens when you try different resolution of the coastlines, just `ax.coastlines()` maybe?

Comment: The coastlines appear when I run the script?

Comment: I'm afraid they still do not appear.

Comment: Could you provide a complete script? We don't know about values of `lat0`, `lon0`, `x_lim`, `y_lim`, `data`.

Comment: Maybe, `pcolormesh` covers the coastlines.

Comment: Ok, I think I have found it. Radius of the Earth was in cm instead of meters. Now the problem seems solved. Thx.